# chart.js 2.0 add new property to dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

i need to add one property to dataset/label to identify it on click. 
I've tried something like this:

```
Chart.controllers.customBar = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
        code: null
    });
```

and it almost works, because i can see new property "code", data is associated with it, chart background is visible but empty, i mean no data from datasets visible.

This is my initialization:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("roads-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.roadsBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: roadsChartData,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Stan dróg"
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label'
            },
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }],
                yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
            },
            onClick: function(e, d) {
                console.log(d);
            }
        }
    });
```

The thing is, i don't feel Chart.js, can someone help me handle it and show an example how does extending work? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could extend the chart to do this, if you don't mind relying on internal properties (that could possibly change in later versions of chart.js), you can just use the `_datasetIndex` and `_index` properties to retrieve your extra properties from the chart configuration, like so

```
  options: {
    onClick: function(e, d) {
      if (d.length > 0) {
        console.log(this.config.data.datasets[d[0]._datasetIndex].code[d[0]._index]);
      }
    }
    ...
```

and

```
  ...
  datasets: [{
    code: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    ...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/55cdvb20/